# Do you know how to obtain Google Maps intersections in Argentina?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Is it possible to obtain the intersections and between street from the Google Maps API for Argentina, Chile or Brazil?

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=true&address=Peatones%2033,%20Santiago,%20Chile

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=true&address=Baez%20800%20Autonomous%20City%20of%20Buenos%20Aires,%20Argentina

Comment: Pudiste resolverlo? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724821/how-to-get-a-longitude-latitude-of-a-intersection

Yo estoy con eso

Answer (score 0):

https://support.google.com/maps/answer/144337#roads

"Note: Intersection search is not available in all countries or languages"